# Form Recognizer - API Call

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

is it possible to get the key value pairs directly from a pdf document (unlabelled) with the help of the api or is the result of an api call always JSON?
I would need the result, given in the screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCIHc.png)

Thank you very much
Andy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please describe what you've tried so far, add some code and some sample data.

Comment: Hi, i tried the example from [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=windows#recognize-form-content[link]         But i only got json as response, so my question is, if i can receive the key value pairs? Thanks andy